# PHP unsetting array in loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to modify an existing array called **field_data** and delete the parent array of the `key->value` pair that has `control == off`. So in this example I would like to unset Array[1]. However it's not working, what am I doing wrong?

```
foreach ($field_data['0'] as &$subsection) {
foreach ($subsection as $key => $value) 
{
if($key=='Control' && $value =='OFF') 
  { echo 'match';  unset($subsection);   }
}
return $field_data;
}
Field_data
----------
    Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [SECTION_ID] => 
                            [Control] => ON

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [SECTION_ID] => 
                            [Control] => OFF

                        )
                  )
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to remove a variable that PHP is still using, specifically the array the inner loop is looping over.

The way you're checking you don't even need the inner loop. I would do something like this:

```
foreach( $field_data[0] as $skey => $svalue ) {
    if( array_key_exists('Control', $svalue) && $svalue['Control'] == 'OFF' ) {
        unset($field_data[0][$skey]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
unset($field_data[0][$subsection]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't modify array you're iterating. 
Create an array of keys to remove instead, then iterate result and unset keys

```
$targets = array(); 
foreach( $field_data[0] as $skey => $svalue ) {
if( array_key_exists('Control', $svalue) && $svalue['Control'] == 'OFF' ) {
    targets[] = $skey;
}

foreach($targets as $target)
{
     unset($field_data[0][$target]);
}
```